# Azure SQL Managed Backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017, azure

I have a SQL 2017 on-prem database server that the client wants to back up to Azure storage directly; instead of using local storage. The largest database backup is 4-5TB. I read the MS documentation and it states this 'SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure uses the Backup to Block Blob feature. The maximum size of a block blob is 200 GB. But by utilizing striping, the maximum size of an individual backup can be up to 12 TB. '
What does it mean by striping?? Do I need to get Premium storage for striping??
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

striping means to use multiple to urls in this way:

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2016

TO URL='https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/b2bb/AdventureWorks-Part1.BAK',

URL='https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/b2bb/AdventureWorks-Part2.BAK',

URL='https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/b2bb/AdventureWorks-Part3.BAK' WITH FORMAT
```

in this way your backup is tripped in three files...

use a script like the one there:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/07/18/sql-server-backup-to-url-script-to-perform-stripped-backup-using-shared-access-signature-sas/

Comment: This is correct, but I would argue that for a 5TB database that backing up to a local drive (using striping) and then copying to the cloud may be more reliable (at least for the FULL)

Comment: I don't think so. It will takes a lot of time and it takes also on-prem space.
And also you need to copy it back in case of restore.
The backups are compressed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if your external connection is rock solid then everything will be great.  However, if you have a blip anytime during the backup it will terminate, wasting any time that has been spent doing the backup, necessitating restarting the process.  Slower, and more storage intensive, yes, but definitely more reliable.  Plus the latest backup is already locally stored for quick access if required.  And yes, if your source machine is already in the cloud, your network connection to azure will be rock solid so my recommendation won't be relevant.